# My SQL Incrementing Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'Serials' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

In My SQL I am getting an error. I heard you can use an 'AS' template to fix this, but I can not figure it out. I am a little new to MYSQL. This works in MSSQL. I am trying to increment the count.

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'Serials' for update in FROM clause

```
UPDATE Serials 
SET activationcount = (SELECT activationcount FROM Serials WHERE Serial = 'XXX') + 1
WHERE Serial = 'XXX'
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after I thought about researching increment techniques.

```
UPDATE Serials 
SET activationcount = activationcount + 1
WHERE Serial = 'XXX'
```

Comment: This works in both databases.  In fact, it is ANSI-compliant SQL that should work in *any* database.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do?

```
UPDATE Serials 
SET activationcount = activationcount + 1
WHERE Serial = 'XXX'
```